# jQuery-UI draggable and droppable items become non draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have 2 divs: #leftDiv and #mainDiv. #leftDiv contains some list items, which are draggable and droppable into #mainDiv, but there is one problem, after drop elements in the #mainDiv become non draggable. What can I do with this? Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#output li').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
  $('#mainDiv').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui){
      var item = $('<div class="foo">').append(ui.draggable.text());
      $(this).append(item);
    }
  });
  $(".foo").draggable();
});
```

I want to make elements in `#mainDiv` draggable and droppable to any place user wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new *foos* that by default are not draggable. You need to make them:

```
item.draggable();
$(this).append(item).
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I have one more question if you could help with this as well. Now, when I drag this item and drop it in the same div, every time a new clone of it appears. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze , this is because you *are* cloning the object. Either don't clone or `.remove` the helper once you're done. Or you might the `original` clone to move the original object? (This depends on your UI design).

Comment: The point is that if the element is dragged from another div, it must be cloned, if it's dragged inside the same div, it must not get cloned. I have tried adding $(ui.helper).remove(); inside the item.draggable();, but did not work.

Comment: I think that `ui.helper` is a jQuery object; have you tried `ui.helper.remove()`?